# How can I make a text field lose focus before application quits?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, focus, windowlistener

I have an application with a JFrame containing text fields. When text in a field is modified, and the field gets a `focusLost` event, it immediately writes its contents to an external database.

However, if the user quits the application while a field is still focused, the `focusLost` message is not sent and the modified data is not saved.

How can I force the loss of focus on a field, perhaps in a `windowClosing` method in my `WindowListener`? I tried using `requestFocusInWindow()` in that method, but it did not help.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just call the same method that writes the contents to the external database from within the windowClosing method of your window listener?

```
@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    // call write to DB method
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: My question simplified the situation a bit. There are several text fields, and each does its write to the database differently. Having the focusLost event sent normally seems easier than having the windowClosing() method determine if there is a focused field and then sending it focusLost, and certainly easier than duplicating all the different database write code.

Comment: @user1198411: your question is an XY Problem -- you're trying to solve the wrong thing. The issue is not how to force a focus-lost event, which doesn't make sense but rather how to write to the database when the application closes. That's what Coop is answering and is what you should focus your efforts on.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of going about it:
Change the `setDefaultCloseOperation` of the `JFrame` to `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`, and show a confirmation dialog when the user wants to close the window.  The dialog will receive focus, triggering the `focusLost` method on the textfield's `FocusListener`.

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            int result = JOptionPane
                    .showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure?", 
                            "Confirm exit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if(result == 0) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }              
        }
    });
```

(Note:  If you go with this method, be sure you don't exit in the middle of writing to the DB.)

Comment: Your final point is well taken. My situation is actually more complex than the original question would suggest. Most of the work (including database writes) in my application is in a worker thread, and I assume the focus events (and shutdown requests) are sent in the event-dispatch thread. Shutting down the application does have to wait for all the stuff in the worker thread to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Pending a better answer that may be forthcoming from someone more experienced that I am, here's what I'm doing.

In my windowClosing() method in my WindowListener, I put:

```
dispatchEvent(new FocusEvent(getFocusOwner(), FocusEvent.FOCUS_LOST));
```